# How to install Windows SDK manually from RAD Studio's setup?

Tags: delphi

I install the RAD Studio 10.1 Berlin Update 2 but didn't setup the Windows SDK after the installation.

Is there a quick way to install the Windows SDK from RAD Studio setup file without re-install again?

Comment: Run the installer, choose Modify. Otherwise, go to Microsoft, download the SDK installer and run it yourself. See http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Installation_Notes

Comment: Also, this is a question that is related to your installation, and you can open a free support ticket for installation issues at [Embarcadero Support](http://support.embarcadero.com) for all installation support questions.